# Why is there no share to social media button on Stack Overflow?

Tags: feature-request

It would be really useful if, having written a question that needs answering, or having found a question and answer that is really useful, I could post it on Twitter or LinkedIn or other social media at the click of a button, using [ShareThis](http://platform.sharethis.com/get-share-buttons), for example.

[image: Vertical button bar created on ShareThis]

Comment: well, that was embarrassing

Comment: No worries, we all have great days we remember ...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Once you click on *share* button, you see the following pop-up. It shares the question with a ref link. It's available on every question and answer.

[image]

There are badges for sharing:
[image]

Comment: oh, the tiny almost invisible grey link... thank you!

Comment: @YvonneAburrow You've found the edit and flag buttons right next to it, that have just as much visibility...

Comment: uhmmmm yes... good point. I guess I expected something a bit more colourful? with social media icons?

Answer (score 3):

There *is* a share button on every post.